# POST Dynamic Data or Mutiple Data in PHP

Tags: php

[image: Snap of edit form]I am new in PHP.I have  a js file

```
    var sites = [
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal/", duration:9},
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9}, 
  //Intro detallee
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/index-t1.html", duration:35},
 //CTA
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/index-t2.html", duration:35},
     //Football
  {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/twitter-ligue/", duration:100},  
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9},     
  //TrailersClub.com
  {url:"http://trailersclub.com/?lang=fr", duration:480},    
 //Heure
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/heure", duration:8},
 //Meteo
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/meteo", duration:12},
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-cine/", duration:9},
 //Cine
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/cine/index-t1.html", duration:150},
  //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-2/", duration:9}, 
 //Heure
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/heure", duration:8},
 //Meteo
 {url:"http://carouselinfo.com/meteo", duration:12},
 //Texte anime
  {url:" http://carouselinfo.com/canal-cine/", duration:9},
   //Cine

 ];
```

PHP code of sanp

```
  for($i=0;$i<count($html);$i++)
 {
 echo '<ul class="link" id="link">';
 echo "<li>".$html[$i]."</li>";
 echo '<span class="main">'.$duration[$i].'</span>';
 echo "</ul>";
   }
```

What I have to do if some one change any data using edit function.Above there is snap of my page so if someone do change in first row only in url then it post the data and data save in js file at row 3 only because if I change on other data or url of js then it will lead to problem so I want to update it at that particular row using POST in AJAX.The problem is there is variable row so how to update at that particular row in js file

Comment: Huh? This doesn't make any sense IMHO. What edit function? What does that screenshot represent? What is that JS array?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa  I have a js file which I call using PHP now if I edit that js file then it automatically save in that file

Comment: How do you call a JS file using PHP?

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa  by using file_get_contents

Answer (score 0):

try to use db/xml/json to store and add/edit/delete the urls duration entries, a php file that manages all could generate the js array and output with header as js.
doc
http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php
although u have to rewrite file to save changes.

Comment: How can I convert to json by json_encode.can you give me link so I can convert it and use it

Comment: i added link for json in php, kind of confused though, you should really use a Database and make use of header function.